# Import everything from a namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

In python you can do "import star" to embed everything from another namespace into the local one:

```
# file "spam":
def ham():
    some code

# file "main":
from spam import *
xy = ham() <-- uses 'ham' from 'spam'
```

This is usually considered "bad practice", but I'm still wondering how to do the same with php namespaces. The following doesn't work:

```
# file "spam":
namespace spam;
function ham() {
    some code
}

# file "main":
include "spam.php";
use spam;    
xy = ham() <-- error
```

Comment: That's strange... i do it everyday and it works everytime. Making a page a.php with function (or public function) a, include it into page b.php and calling the a function.

Comment: @Goikiu: good point, but I'd like to keep "spam" namespaced, so that whoever uses it has a choice.

Comment: *"Neither functions nor constants can be imported via the use statement."* - http://php.net/language.namespaces.faq#language.namespaces.faq.nofuncconstantuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you do not "import from" a namespace. You can only alias a namespace or class to another (presumably shorter) name. So typically you do this:

```
use Foo as F;

new F\Bar;
```

That's the PHP "equivalent" to "using everything from a namespace as conveniently as possible".

Comment: As a side note, that kind of aliasing may kill readability.

Comment: Or drastically improve it, depending on the situation.

Comment: So, the answer is "no way"?

Comment: @thg Yes, no way, because PHP's and Python's mechanisms are actually very different. Apples and oranges.

Comment: Ok, `use spam\ham` doesn't work either. Is this expected?

Comment: @thg You can only alias *namespaces or classes*, not functions.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no way to include all classes in a namespace with a single line, the way one can with just about any other language, I find it endlessly helpful to have an IDE handle the "use" cases automatically.

I highly recommend looking into [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (it's my personal favorite). It does a wonderful job automatically writing the "use" lines when using the auto-complete features.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-imports.html